# How does client - web server mechanism of check for latest modified date work?

Tags: apache-http-server, http, webserver, browser-cache, date-modified

I know that a web browser check if a resource is modified/expired within a given timestamp to decide if downloading such resource or not.

So, here come two questions:

i) generally speaking how exactly this mechanism works in background, which requests/reponse are made by browser and server

ii) I have built a simple REST php web service that serves a json file by means of GET request. And GET is actually the only protocol implemented. In the response I am correctly including all the necessary header file. Is there something server side I need to implement for making my web service compliant to such 'check for last update therefore serve or not the resource' mechanism ? In particular my client is an iOS app, which by default is strictly following the http caching rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTTP supports several forms of cache control<sup>1</sup>:

#### Server-side

The server can specify the headers [Cache-Control](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.9), [ETag](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.19), [Expires](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.21) and [Last-Modified](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.29).

- *Cache-Control* contains general instructions, i.e., if, how and until when the resource may be cached.
- *ETag* is an arbitrary but fixed string that the server will change if the resource changes.
- *Expires* indicates until when the client doesn't have to check for a new version of the resource.

  This is commonly used in combination with cache breakers. If you address `script.js` as `script.js?versionX` (JavaScript files will ignore the query), you can set an arbitrary expiration date. If the script ever changes, you can just address it as `script.js?versionY`.
- *Last-Modified* indicates the last modification date of the resource.

#### Client-side

Once the client has cached a certain resource using any of the above methods, it can proceed as follows:

- If the resource hasn't expired yet (*Cache-Control* and *Expires* are relevant), do not request it.
- Send the GET request with an [If-Modified-Since](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26) and/or [If-None-Match](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.26), indicating the *ETag* and/or *Last-Modified* header that was received when the resource was cached.

  Depending on those headers, the server may send the HTTP status code 304, indicating that the resource has not been modified. In this case, the client has to read the resource from the cache.

<sub><sup>1</sup>These are the methods I personally know of. There may be more.</sub>

Comment: thanks, so when a GET request come in, I need to analyze if the if-modified, E-Tag and the rest are present in such request, and in case I can match with my criteria and answer with a 304 or with the full resource and 200 status code ?

Comment: All of these are optional. If you send *ETag*, analyze *If-None-Match*. If you send *Last-Modified*, analyze *If-Modified-Since*. My personal favorite is *Expires* plus cache breaker. That way, the client won't make any requests, and you don't have to analyze anything.